# $f$ and $m$ are polynomials over the field $K$. Prove that if $f=pm+r$, $r≠0$, then their hcf is $1$

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

$f$ and $m$ are polynomials over the field $K$.

$m$ is irreducible.

Prove that if $f=pm+r$ (dividing $f$ by $m$ with the division algorithm over $K$), $r≠0$, then the hcf of $f$ and $m$ is $1$

The author assumed it without giving any proof, and it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Post the full question, this is too vague. If m and r are both polynomials, it sounds fake

Comment: And, importantly: what is $g$?

Comment: @user8734617. Sorry, I wrote $g$ instead of $m$

Comment: Do they possibly say/assume that $r\in K$, i.e. that $r$ is a *constant* polynomial?

Comment: @userr8734617. No. I think I have to rewrite the question.

Comment: I was asking that because *that* condition would make the statement true, while, without it, you can have numerous counterexamples as demonstrated in the answers.

Comment: I added "$m$ is irreducible". Would there still be counterexamples including this condition?

Comment: Nope, that would make it true. If $m$ is irreducible, then $\operatorname{hcf}(f,m)$ is either $1$ or $m$ itself, but then, if the latter, $m$ would divide $f$ and so the remainder $r$ would be zero.